# Remove Unwanted/Extra Data in SQLPLUS

Tags: sql, batch-file, oracle11g, sqlplus

I am running a  file via batch file

Batch File:

```
sqlplus admin/admin@SERVER @abc.sql > output.txt
```

SQL File abc.sql:

```
set PAGESIZE 1000
set LINESIZE 550
set echo off
set head off
set FEEDBACK OFF
select * from S_ABC
exit;
```

Output.txt:

```
Connected To:
Oracle Database 11g................................
.
.
.
DATA
.
.
Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g .......
.
.
```

Please help me remove the extra data, in the starting and end of output.txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-S` seems to be what you're looking for;

```
sqlplus -S admin/admin@SERVER @abc.sql > output.txt
```

> [-S[ILENT]](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch4.htm#1006196)
>
> Suppresses all SQL*Plus information and prompt messages, including the command prompt, the echoing of commands, and the banner normally displayed when you start SQL*Plus. If you omit username or password, SQL*Plus prompts for them, but the prompts are not visible. Use SILENT to invoke SQL*Plus within another program so that the use of SQL*Plus is invisible to the user.

Comment: I am also getting a blank line before the data in the text file, please help me to remove that

Comment: @bhaviksanghvi - use `set pagesize 0` instead of 1000; you don't need to explicitly `set head off` either with that.